# Accurate Venn diagrams using eulerr

Tags: r, list, venn-diagram, eulerr

I'm trying to use the eulerr package to create Venn diagrams. I have 2 lists that I would like to use to create the Venn diagram with. 1 of the lists is a subset of the first. Strangely, eulerr seems to think that there is one value present in list

```
b
```

that is unique to that subset. I can't seem to figure out which values it thinks are unique.

https://pastebin.com/J7tPcfAt

```
> length(a)
[1] 3278

> length(b)
[1] 1318
```

When I check overlap between the subsets I get the expected results:

```
> length(which(a %in% b))
[1] 1318

> length(which((b %in% a)))
[1] 1318

> length(which(!(b %in% a)))
[1] 0

> length(which(!(a %in% b)))
[1] 1960
```

But when I use eulerr to plot a Venn diagram I get:

```
library(eulerr)
fit <- euler(list("A" = a, "B" = b))
plot(fit, counts = TRUE)
```

[image]

Notably, the number of values that eulerr thinks are unique to A is one longer than what I get using

```
length(which(!(a %in b)))
```

Any help understanding this behavior would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could share the data via https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Thanks! Just updated the question to include the lists via pastebin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what's causing this behaviour but I can't explain why. It's because there is a duplicate value in both `a` and `b`, and it's the same value.

```
> a[duplicated(a)]
[1] "Crybg3"
> b[duplicated(b)]
[1] "Crybg3"
```

If I remove this value from both vectors it works.

```
a1 <- a[!duplicated(a)]
b1 <- b[!duplicated(b)]

fit <- euler(list("A" = a1, "B" = b1))
plot(fit, counts = TRUE)

> fit
    original fitted residuals region_error
A       1960   1960         0            0
B          0      0         0            0
A&B     1317   1317         0            0

diag_error:  0 
stress:      0
```

[image]

Comment: I am the author of this package. The items in the list (for the list method) should not contain any duplicates, Think of the contents of each set as people that can either belong to a set or not and cannot be twice included in a set. In the next update I'll make sure the function checks for this.